# SQLAlchemy connection hangs on AWS MySQL RDS reboot with failover

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, rds

We have a Python server which uses SQLAlchemy to read/write data from an AWS MySQL MultiAZ RDS instance.

We're experiencing a behavior we'd like to avoid where whenever we trigger a failover reboot, a connection which was open already and then issues a statement hangs indefinitely. While this is something to expect according to AWS documentation, we would expect the Python MySQL connector would be able to cope with this situation.

The closest case we've found on the web is this [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/NANPH1QWgMM) which talks about the issue and offers a solution regarding a Postgres RDS.

For example, the below script will hang indefinitely when initiating a failover reboot (adopted from the above mention google groups thread).

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time, sleep
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

import logging

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time() * 1000))
Base = declarative_base()

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(lineno)s %(process)d %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level="INFO")

class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = Column(String(450), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('mysql://<username>:<password>@<db_host>/<db_name>',echo=False, pool_recycle=1800,)
session_maker = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False))
session = session_maker()

while True:
    try:
        ids = ''
        start = current_milli_time()
        for msg in session.query(Message).order_by(Message.id.desc()).limit(5):
            ids += str(msg.id) + ', '
            logging.info('({!s}) (took {!s} ms) fetched ids: {!s}'.format(datetime.now().time().isoformat(), current_milli_time() - start, ids))

        start = current_milli_time()
        m = Message()
        m.body = 'some text'
        session.add(m)
        session.commit()
        logging.info('({!s}) (took {!s} ms) inserted new message'.format(datetime.now().time().isoformat(), current_milli_time() - start))

    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session_maker.remove()

    sleep(0.25)
```

We've tried playing with the connection timeouts but it seems the issue is related to an already opened connection which simply hangs once AWS switches to the failover instance.

Our question is - has anyone encountered this issue or has possible directions worthwhile checking?

Comment: It is definitely not supposed to be seamless to the clients. From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RebootInstance.html): "When you force a failover of your DB instance, Amazon RDS automatically switches to a standby replica in another Availability Zone and updates the DNS record for the DB instance to point to the standby DB instance. As a result, you will need to clean up and re-establish any existing connections to your DB instance."

Comment: You're totally correct, I'm wondering if the Python DB connector has a way of sensing this situation

Comment: How are you setting connection timeouts? If the problem is with existing connections, it sounds like the remote host isn't sending a FIN packet when it's shutting down, which is worrying. Normally, when you gracefully shut down a host, applications will close open socket connections gracefully. A connection should not hang unless some router in the middle is dropping TCP RST packets.

Comment: First of all, I've edited the question to reflect your comment about AWS documentation. About timeouts, that seems to have no effect if the failover happens after the connection opened. I've tried searching for ways to effect socket timeouts specifically through SQLAlchemy but come out short

Comment: Can you show the specific code for how you are setting the timeout?

Comment: sure:

`engine = create_engine('mysql://<username>:<password>@<db_host>/<db_name>', echo=False, pool_recycle=1800, connect_args = {'connect_timeout': <x_seconds>})` 

or 

`engine = create_engine('mysql://<username>:<password>@<db_host>/<db_name>?connect_timeout=<x_seconds>', echo=False, pool_recycle=1800)`

Comment: Bare in mind that, there is many MySQL connector for SQLAlchemy, you never know which one actually work for the timeout switch over conditions
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, for now I'm leaving this as the effort seems to great for the return. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, using SQL connector timeout to handle switchcover is like black magic. Each connector always act differently and difficult to diagnose.

If you read @univerio comment again, AWS will reassign a new IP address for the SAME RDS endpoint name.  While doing the switching, your RDS endpoint name and old IP adderss is still inside your server instance DNS cache. So this is a DNS caching issues, and that's why AWS ask you to "clean up....".

Unless you restart SQLAlchemy to read the DNS again, there is no way that the session know something happens and switch it dynamically. And worst, the issue can be happens in connector that used by SQLAlchemy.

IMHO, it doesn't worth the effort to deal with switch over inside the code. I will just subscribe to AWS service like lambda that can act upon switch over events, trigger the app server to restart the connection, which suppose to reflect the new IP address.